# Não consigo visualizar os votos positivos e negativos na versão mobile?

Tags: suporte, votos

Estou começando a acessar mais o StackOverflowPT pelo smartphone para tentar ficar mais ativo na comunidade e já vi que ele é um pouco limitado que a versão desktop. Porém, achei estranho um recurso tão simples não existir: **visualizar votos positivos e negativos nas postagens**.

Isso é um bug ou realmente não tem como ver?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não sei, mas parece que não :P

O mobile, hoje (pode mudar), é cidadão de segunda classe, e faz sentido, afinal um celular não é muito adequado para fazer perguntas e dar respostas, nem mesmo ler respostas não deveria ser tão usado, porque se precisa da resposta está programando em um desktop. Pode servir para mostrar para um amigo em um conversa algo postado aqui como argumento da discussão.

Mas está havendo mudanças de *design* na UI do site para melhor adaptar ao mobile e talvez mudem o app também, mas não posso afirmar. Não sei se precisa, para consulta eventual a web é boa e se melhorarem mais acho que será suficiente.

Experimente fazer na web, se bobear vai gostar mais que o app.

Comment: Entendi! Comecei a utilizá-lo para fazer edições em postagens quando acho necessário e também para responder comentários. Realmente, só de pensar em elaborar uma resposta ou pergunta num smartphone já fico cansado, rsrs. Mas beleza, vou aguardar as alterações, venho acompanhando algumas delas que estão ocorrendo no SOen, acho que vai ficar bom!

Answer (score 3):

A versão servida para mobiles não tem muitas das funcionalidades da versão servida para desktop. Além de não ver os votos, você também não vê links para as filas de análise, por exemplo. Ao menos em alguns sites da rede, a fila de análise é sempre servida na versão desktop, mesmo que você acesse de um dispositivo móvel.

Se você realmente quiser ver os votos na versão mobile, você pode utilizar a opção "site para computador" ou equivalente do navegador móvel. Mas não é uma experiência agradável.